# Undesired result in canvas shape drawing (html5)

Tags: html, html5-canvas

I was trying to draw a simple rhombus shape with canvas element.
I used this code:

```
cxt.beginPath();
cxt.moveTo(100,100);
cxt.lineTo(50,150);
cxt.lineTo(100,200);
cxt.lineTo(150,150);
cxt.lineTo(100,100);
cxt.closePath();
cxt.strokeStyle = 'black';
cxt.stroke();
cxt.fillStyle='yellow';
cxt.fill();
```

But, output is two-sided triangle! (Printscreen below:)

[image]

**Help me figure out what's wrong..!**

browser used: *mozilla firefox 43.0.4*

Comment: what is you canvas height. Increase the height of canvas

Comment: The image is being cropped due to height too small.

Comment: @TamilSelvan. Your comment is the correct answer. You might post an answer so this question can be closed & removed from the "unanswered" queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the height of the canvas.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("shape");
var cxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
cxt.beginPath();
cxt.moveTo(100,100);
cxt.lineTo(50,150);
cxt.lineTo(100,200);
cxt.lineTo(150,150);
cxt.lineTo(100,100);
cxt.closePath();
cxt.strokeStyle = 'black';
cxt.stroke();
cxt.fillStyle='yellow';
cxt.fill();
```

```html
<canvas id="shape" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```